# A simple question about Leibniz Criterion and the limit comparison test for series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, real-numbers

In a series we can take a factor that doesn't alternate and proof that it is convergent which by the definition of Leibniz criteria means the whole series is also convergent. I get that.

In lecture we shown that the non alternating factor is convergent by using the limit comparison test $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{c_n}{b_n} = L \in (0, \infty) \text{ and } c_n,b_n > 0 $
But what if one of the $c_n$ or $b_n$ are less than zero.

The example we have done was:

$$\sum^\infty_{n = 1}(-1)^{n-1}\tan(\frac{1}{n\sqrt{n}}) $$
where we take out $\tan(x)$ which doesn't alternate for Leibnitz criteria.
We then showed:
$$ \tan(\frac{1}{n\sqrt{n}}) = c_n \text{ is almost the same as } \frac{1}{n^{3/2}} = b_n$$

Then we solved the proof of convergence by using the limit comparison test as mentioned above.

What should we do if the other factor is negative ? Why did we use limit comparison test here instead of any other (do we always have to?) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$0<\tan\left(\frac{1}{n\sqrt n}\right)<\tan 1$ for any $n$ (positivity) and $\underset{n\to \infty }{\text{lim}} \tan\left(\frac{1}{n\sqrt n}\right)=0$ are the conditions of Leibniz test.

The comparison test is not necessary. Even $\sum _{n=2}^{\infty } (-1)^n \log n$ converges.

An  [alternating series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test#Formulation) must have *all* terms positive or all terms negative, otherwise the Leibniz test doesn't apply. If they are all negative you can collect the minus sign like the following example:
$$\sum _{n=2}^{\infty } \frac{(-1)^n}{1-n^2}=-\sum _{n=2}^{\infty } \frac{(-1)^n}{n^2-1}$$

Comment: I meant in general, that $b_n$ or $c_n$ is negative, regardless of the example

Comment: @BiliDebili I added the answer to the second part of the question